# How can I increase the number of downloads shown in the download panel?

Tags: macos, firefox

Firefox 20 has a new *downloads panel* feature. But it only shows the [three most recently downloaded files](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/find-and-manage-downloaded-files?esab=a&s=download+manager&r=0&as=s#w_how-do-i-access-my-downloads).

> [image: Description from linked web site]

How can I increase that number?

Answer (score 9):

> <sup>This answer does not work in newer Firefox versions anymore, but it's still valid for Firefox 20, so I'm keeping this around.</sup>

Currently there is no setting in `about:config` to customize this value. It is hard-coded in the Firefox UI scripts.

1. Right-click Firefox.app, and select *Show Content*. Navigate to `Contents/MacOS` and copy the `omni.ja` file to your Desktop. Rename the copied file to `omni.zip` and extract it.
2. Change the file `omni/chrome/browser/content/browser/downloads/downloads.js`. Look for the following lines:

   ```
     /**
      * Maximum number of items shown by the list at any given time.
      */
     kItemCountLimit: 3,
   ```

   Replace that value with e.g. `10`.
3. Change the file `omni/modules/DownloadsCommon.jsm`. Look for the following lines:

   ```
   if (PrivateBrowsingUtils.isWindowPrivate(aWindow)) {
     if (this._privateSummary) {
       return this._privateSummary;
     }
     return this._privateSummary = new DownloadsSummaryData(true, aNumToExclude);
   } else {
     if (this._summary) {
       return this._summary;
     }
     return this._summary = new DownloadsSummaryData(false, aNumToExclude);
   ```

   Replace occurrences of `aNumToExclude` with `10`.
4. Save both files, and compress the contents of the `omni` directory (so that the resulting archive does *not* contain a top-level folder named `omni`). Rename the resulting file to `omni.ja` (via the file's *Get Info* dialog -- .ja isn't a known file extension and Finder will probably interpret it as omni.ja.zip otherwise).
5. Replace the original `omni.ja` file with your modified one.
6. Restart Firefox once in safe mode by holding down <kbd>Option</kbd> while starting to apply the changes.

Result:

[image: Screenshot]

---

Remember that changes like described above need to be reapplied every time Firefox is updated.

Comment: The same method should work on Windows (and presumably Linux). The `omni.ja` file is available in the root Firefox installation directory, typically either `%ProgramFiles(x86)\Mozilla Firefox` on 64-bit versions of Windows, or `%ProgramFiles%\Mozilla Firefox` on 32-bit versions of Windows.